# SQL SP sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql

Alterei a SP `[msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]` colocando novo parâmetro na mesma.

Existe algum momento onde esta SP seja actualizada e se percam as alterações realizadas? (SQL Server 2017)

Obrigado

Comment: Se calhar a melhor solução seria mesmo duplicar essa SP para uma sua. Não acredito que alterar SPs nativas do SQL seja boa ideia.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Estou tendo dificuldades em entender como executo esse código..

Comment: EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Como faço para executar esse código com a tabela que pretendo?